# Custom Xib UITableViewCell with UITextField: Trouble with Delegates and Dequequing

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have am creating custom cells for my TableView. I have 8 different kinds of cells. This is happening for all the cells but I will pick one for this example to demonstrate what is going on. My cell NumberCell has a TextField in it. Below you can see how I setup the cell with GetCell and SetupDelegates. Everything works fine until I have enough cells on the screen that you must start scrolling to create new cells of the same type (which dequeues and reuses old cells). Well my cell's seem to be swapping answerNumberField.Text when I scroll them off the screen and then back on and maybe it has something to do with sending the formItem into the custom cell, but I'm not sure. I guess I would like to know if this is the correct way to be setting up my delegates inside my custom cell. You can see the reason I did was so that I could have access to the formItem information while in the cell, but this could be what's causing the issue. I also did it to try and separate out the logic so that my GetCell didn't get huge. Any help would be much appreciated and if you need anymore info just ask. Thanks!

Registering the custom cell's xib file:

```
TableView.RegisterNibForCellReuse (MFNumberCell.Nib, MFNumberCell.Key);
```

**GetCell**

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var cell = new UITableViewCell();
        FormItem formItem = formItems [indexPath.Row];

        switch (formItem.type) {
          case "MFNumber":
            var numberCell = (MFNumberCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell (MFNumberCell.Key, indexPath);
            numberCell.SetupDelegates (formItem, detailVC);
            cell = numberCell;
            break;

           ...
        }
        //Remove inset edge constraints
        cell.SeparatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.Zero;
        cell.LayoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.Zero;

        //Don't show background highlight when selecting the cell
        cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;


        return cell;
    }
```

**Custom NumberCell**

```
public void SetupDelegates (FormItem formItem, DetailViewController detailVC)
    {  

        validationView.Layer.MasksToBounds = false;
        validationView.Layer.CornerRadius = 13;

        //Adds left space before text
        answerNumberField.LeftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
        if (answerNumberField.LeftView == null) {
            UIView leftView = new UIView (new CGRect (0, 0, 15, 25));
            answerNumberField.LeftView = leftView;
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (formItem.answer)) {
            answerNumberField.Text = formItem.answer;
        } else {
            answerNumberField.Text = "";
        }

        answerNumberField.Placeholder = formItem.placeholder;
        answerNumberField.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad;
        questionTextView.Text = formItem.question_text;
        UtilHelper.UpdateValidationView(formItem, validationView);


        helpButton.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
            var okAlertController = UIAlertController.Create ("Help", formItem.help, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
            okAlertController.AddAction (UIAlertAction.Create ("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));
            detailVC.PresentViewController (okAlertController, true, null);
        };



        answerNumberField.ShouldChangeCharacters += (UITextField tf, NSRange range, string replacementText) => {
            string next_answer = tf.Text + replacementText;
            bool isMatch = Regex.IsMatch(next_answer, formItem.input_constraint);

            if(isMatch){ 
                formItem.answer = next_answer;
            }

            UtilHelper.UpdateValidationView(formItem, validationView);

            return isMatch;
        };


        answerNumberField.Ended += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {

            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(answerNumberField.Text)) {
                formItem.answer = "";
            }else{
                formItem.answer = answerNumberField.Text;
            }

            FormGenerator.updateFormItemInSQLiteDatabase (formItem);
            UtilHelper.UpdateValidationView(formItem, validationView);

        };

    }
```

**Here's the Solution that worked for me**

Create EventHandlers and save them to the cell so that you can call the Remove method in the CellDisplayingEnded method of your TableViewSource.

```
public partial class MFNumberCell : UITableViewCell
{
    public static readonly UINib Nib = UINib.FromName ("MFNumberCell", NSBundle.MainBundle);
    public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString ("MFNumberCell");

    public EventHandler helpButtonClick;
    public UITextFieldChange answerFieldShouldChangeChar;
    public EventHandler answerFieldEnded;


    public MFNumberCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public static MFNumberCell Create ()
    {
        return (MFNumberCell)Nib.Instantiate (null, null) [0];
    }


    public void Update (FormItem formItem, DetailViewController detailVC)
    {  

        validationView.Layer.MasksToBounds = false;
        validationView.Layer.CornerRadius = 13;

        //Adds left space before text
        answerNumberField.LeftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
        if (answerNumberField.LeftView == null) {
            UIView leftView = new UIView (new CGRect (0, 0, 15, 25));
            answerNumberField.LeftView = leftView;
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (formItem.answer)) {
            answerNumberField.Text = formItem.answer;
        } else {
            answerNumberField.Text = "";
        }

        answerNumberField.Placeholder = formItem.placeholder;
        answerNumberField.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad;
        questionTextView.Text = formItem.question_text;
        UtilHelper.UpdateValidationView(formItem, validationView);


        // HELP BUTTON START //

        helpButtonClick = (s, e) => { 
            var okAlertController = UIAlertController.Create ("Help", formItem.help, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
            okAlertController.AddAction (UIAlertAction.Create ("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));
            detailVC.PresentViewController (okAlertController, true, null); 
        };

        helpButton.TouchUpInside += helpButtonClick;


        // HELP BUTTON END // 

        // ANSWER TEXT FIELD START //

        answerFieldShouldChangeChar =  (UITextField tf, NSRange range, string replacementText) => {
            string next_answer = tf.Text + replacementText;
            bool isMatch = Regex.IsMatch(next_answer, formItem.input_constraint);

            if(isMatch){ 
                formItem.answer = next_answer;
            }

            UtilHelper.UpdateValidationView(formItem, validationView);

            return isMatch;
        };

        answerNumberField.ShouldChangeCharacters += (UITextFieldChange)answerFieldShouldChangeChar;


        answerFieldEnded = (s, e) => {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (answerNumberField.Text)) {
                formItem.answer = "";
            } else {
                formItem.answer = answerNumberField.Text;
            }

            FormGenerator.updateFormItemInSQLiteDatabase (formItem);
            UtilHelper.UpdateValidationView (formItem, validationView);
        };

        answerNumberField.Ended += answerFieldEnded;

        // ANSWER TEXT FIELD END //


    }

    public void RemoveDelegates(){
        answerNumberField.Ended -= answerFieldEnded;
        answerNumberField.ShouldChangeCharacters -= answerFieldShouldChangeChar;
        helpButton.TouchUpInside -= helpButtonClick; 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since every time cell is about to appear  you assign Delegates in GetCell(), you should also remove them each time the cell is about to disappear in CellDisplayingEnded()

you should do a method in MFNumberCell named RemoveDelegates
and call it on CellDisplayingEnded()

Comment: @JordanHochstetler please mark the question as answer if it helped out

Comment: @iamlcarus I spoke too soon. It seems like the bug is back. Maybe its doesn't have to do with the delegates but its the way cells are being Dequeued.

Comment: @iamlcarus Whoops! Syntax... I was using '+=' where I should have been using '=' when assigning UITextFieldChange answerFieldShouldChangeChar. Thanks for help on troubleshooting this issue!